# Docker service doesn't auto start after moving the docker image data directory to external drive location

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

Following this [page](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-change-docker-image-location-for-xray-without-changing-docker-client-setting/), I have moved the docker data directory and created a symbolic link to it. It works. But everytime after rebooting my computer, the Docker service doesn't start automatically any more. How can I solve this problem?

**`journalctl -u docker.service` returns**:

```
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu dockerd[2358]: time="2022-06-30T10:29:55.426467188+10:00" level=info msg="S>
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu dockerd[2358]: mkdir /var/lib/docker: file exists
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL>
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 30 10:29:55 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 30 10:29:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jun 30 10:29:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 30 10:29:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 30 10:29:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 30 10:29:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Before moving the data directory "*/var/lib/docker*", it was a **directory** used by Docker, now it is a **symbolic link** that points to the external directory where the docker image data is stored. Why there is a `mkdir` command?

If I run `dockerd`, it returns:

```
INFO[2022-06-30T20:53:05.143671302+10:00] Starting up                                  
dockerd needs to be started with root privileges. To run dockerd in rootless mode as an unprivileged user, see https://docs.docker.com/go/rootless/
```

If I run `sudo service docker start`, docker can start without error. But I don't want to run this everyday. Docker used to start automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: It clearly dislikes that `/var/lib/docker` already exists.

Comment: Use **/etc/docker/daemon.json** for specify new **Docker Root Dir** with `{  "data-root": "/new/dir" }` ; then restart docker and check the output of `docker info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error message with the same configuration:

```
 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
 dockerd[47623]: time="2022-06-30T16:36:20.047741616Z" level=in..
 dockerd[47623]: mkdir /data/docker: file exists
 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, ..
```

The reason was that my external drive wasn't mounted yet.

Adding systemd mount/automount units resolve the issue. Or you can add your external drive to your /etc/fstab (Add **nofail** for avoid the  90 seconds wait when you don't have it with you).

Also from  [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/):

> You can configure the Docker daemon to use a different directory, using the data-root configuration option.

So editing your **/etc/docker/daemon.json** with:

```json
{
  "data-root": "/data/docker"
}
```

is probably better than using symlinks.

Comment: Thanks! So the issue is **because dockerd starts before the external drive was even mounted**. If dockerd can't find the docker data directory it tried to create one at the specified location. I edited the **/etc/docker/daemon.json** file, it turned out docker created the dir itself a the specified location (/media/name/Elements/docker), and my external drive was then mounted with new dir names (/media/name/Elements1).